# Dll is missing right after publishing it. .net WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, dllimport

Where the files of published project will go after installing it ? I tried putting the DLL inside of the setup folder there yet it has still a same problem.

I'm trying to use the DLL using pinvoke

```
[DllImport("tc-b_new_sdk.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
```

I receive this error:

```
System.DllNotFoundException: 
Unable to load DLL 'tc-b_new_sdk.dll': The specified module could not be found. 
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

Comment: This is vauge, what you mean setup up folder, also if you include a file in your projects (which maybe you mean), you will have to make set the properties on it

Comment: The setup folder is the folder of published projects. and also i didn't add any reference inside of the visual studio I'm only calling it via code. ``[DllImport("tc-b_new_sdk.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]`` like this.

Comment: Sounds like an Anviz product, exported names start with CChex  Avoid SO users from having to guess.  It doesn't have any special dependencies, so whatever "putting the DLL inside of the setup folder" might mean wasn't enough to convince the installer to deploy the DLL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding Path of your DLL like this :

```
[DllImport("C:\Users\User\Desktop\tc-b_new_sdk.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
```

Answer (score -1):

Either the DLL itself, or one of its dependencies cannot be found.

If the DLL is in the same directory as the executable, this points to the issue being the dependencies. We can't know what the dependencies are. That information should have been supplied with the DLL. A common cause of this error is that your program isn't able to resolve a dependency on the MSVC to which the DLL is linked.

Comment: When I'm trying to execute it in my visual studio it is working and when I'm getting the executable in Debug folder it is working when it is published it is not already working.

Comment: I stand by what I wrote in my answer.